# Creating and Using Variables in DB2 SQL

Tags: sql, variables, db2

I'm trying to create a variable to use in a Where clause in db2 sql.  Everything runs without errors, but I don't return any results.  Could you please have a look at the below and tell me where I'm going wrong?

--CREATE MY TEST TABLE

CREATE TABLE QTEMP.TESTVAR (CYCLE CHAR(2), BD CHAR(2));
INSERT INTO QTEMP.TESTVAR (CYCLE, BD) VALUES (01,01),(02,02),(03,03),(04,04),(05,05),(06,06),(07,07),(08,08),(09,09),(10,10),(11,11),(12,12),(13,13),(14,14),(15,15);

--CREATE MY VARIABLE

DROP VARIABLE SRCCYC; CREATE VARIABLE SRCCYC CHAR(10) DEFAULT ' ''13'',''14'',''15'' ';

-- SQL WITH VARIABLE DOESN'T WORK

SELECT * FROM QTEMP.TESTVAR WHERE CYCLE IN (SRCCYC);

--THIS IS WHAT I WANT IT TO BRING BACK

SELECT * FROM QTEMP.TESTVAR WHERE CYCLE IN ('13','14','15');

Answer (score 0):

You don't mention the platform and Db2 version you are using...

However, this `IN ('13','14','15')` is a hard-coded set of three string values...

This `IN (SRCCYC)` is a set with just a single string value.

What you need is something like so:
`IN (SRCCYC1, SRCCYC2, SRCCYC3)`

Depending on your platform and version you might be able to use `JSON_TABLE()`, `XML_TABLE()` or a provided/existing/roll-your-own `SPLIT()` function to split the single string into a multi-row temporary table compatible with `IN ()`